# deleting a contact from address book using personViewController

Tags: ios, abaddressbook, abpersonviewcontroller

I am getting hand over the address book and created it successfully without any option of 'deleting a contact' from address book.

Is there any method to delete contact from address book.

I got help from i`OS reference library`.

I am using `personViewController` methods

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ABPersonViewController+Delete category which does not use any private methods:

https://github.com/shrtlist/ABDelete